# Not able to retrieve attributes from the userIdentity object in worklight client

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-security

Iam using worklight 6.0 and I have custom securityTest for the adapter.

```
In the loginModule, im adding few custom attributes for the userIdentity

public UserIdentity createIdentity(String loginModule) {
        HashMap<String, Object> customAttributes = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        customAttributes.put("AuthenticationDate", new Date());
        customAttributes.put("userIdentity", USERIDENTITY);     
        UserIdentity identity = new UserIdentity("CustomAuthenticatorRealm", USERNAME, null, null, customAttributes, PASSWORD);
        return identity;
    }
In the client side,

var attrs = WL.Client.getUserInfo("CustomAuthenticatorRealm", "attributes");

Sometimes Iam getting the attributes and sometimes as null.

Please help me on this.
```

Answer (score 1):

The user identity attributes are returned to client after successful authentication. In case you're not going through authentication process you can use this API to refresh user data - http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.worklight.help.doc%2Fapiref%2Fr_wl_client_updateuserinfo.html

Comment: Iam going through the authentication process. eventhen, im not able to retrieve the attrs var